# SQL Server full text search error: Full-text crawl manager has not been initialized

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm just trying out full text search in SQL Server 2008 and am failing at the first hurdle. I've created an index, but when I try to populate it using:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON TableName SET CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 7644, Level 17, State 1, Line 1
>
> Full-text crawl manager has not been initialized. Any crawl started before the crawl manager was fully initialized will need to be restarted. Please restart SQL Server and retry the command. You should also check the error log to fix any failures that might have caused the crawl manager to fail.

Obviously I've tried restarting SQL Server, but still get the same message.

I found a [KB article for SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961662) about an invalid `FTSGroup` registry key but I can't find any indication that this also applies to SQL Server 2008, my feeling is that it probably doesn't.

Anybody know what's wrong and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I never worked out how to fix it, but at least I earned the Tumbleweed badge. Some consolation I guess. So I just got a new machine built instead of fixing it. That works, if anyone's ever looking for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I received the same error message when I restored a database *with* a full text catalog to a new machine that had SQL Server 2012 installed *without* the full text feature checked.  Once I installed the feature I was able to populate the index.